# Is it possible for multiple Docker Swarm Services to access an env_file that is located on a volume mount?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, swarm

I am trying to use a single env_file in multiple Docker Swarm Services. The volume mount point and file are available in the container. I validated it by logging into the running container. As soon as I deploy the stack's .yml file I receive an error stating that the .env file could not be found.

This is what I have done:

First, added a volume to a service in any given stack.

```
volumes:
 - /environment:/environment
```

Then, include the .env file directive

```
env_file:
  - /environment/.env
```

Is it at all possible to use an env_file that is located on a volume mount? I might be worth to note that the volume mount resolves to a NFS volume on the host and that I am using Swarmpit. However it seems that deploying the stack on the command line yields to the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `env_file` option points to a file on the deployment server, not necessarily the node running the containers, and not to a file inside the container. I believe the contents are expanded by the docker client, converted into environment entries in the container definition, and you will see the container running with the result.

Because of this, there is no need for the file to be mounted as a volume.

However, it is necessary for the file to exist where you run the docker client (docker is a client/server based application, often communicating over the docker socket). With Swarmpit, that client is likely inside of a container, where your files on the host will not be visible and cannot be expanded.

Comment: This aspect of Docker is very confusing to me. My Swarm setup is a single node setup where Master==Node. So I thought that according to your response after removing the "volumes:" directive it should find the "/environment/.env" env_file. But it doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: @Jabb please include the output of `ls -l /environment/.env` and your deploy command and it's output in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts.Just found that on the console it is working all fine when run on the terminal. This seems to be an issue with swarmpit, where the env_files directive is not parsed and expanded to environment variables in the compose file.